# timer.schedule did not run as planned

Tags: java, scheduler

```
public class TestTask {
    Timer time=new Timer("TestTask");
    int period=Integer.ValueOf("17680000"); // 200days
    TimerSuite sut=new TimerSuite();
    time.schedule()；
    timer.schedule(sut, 0, period);
}
```

I want the schedule to execute in 200 days after it has executed the first time. Actually the first time schedule is called is *23:01:45 April 22*, 
but the next time when the schedule is called is *12:57:99 April 23*.

Now I am confused why the schedule cannot be called as planned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)), the `period` parameter you are using is defined as:

> period - time in milliseconds between successive task executions.

200 days correspond to 17680000000 milliseconds. Here you seem to have specified seconds instead (17680000), and your timer is therefore being called only after a few hours.

Comment: That was my first thought too, except that the number of milliseconds specified is just under five hours, whereas the period that OP claims the task was scheduled for is approximately 14 hours.

Comment: Thank you。I have resolved  it。  17680000000  >（2 to the power of 15 -1）

Comment: Thank you for your answer sincerely.I am a newer，Could you tell me how to mark?

Comment: @Yetion: There's a good post describing that here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235